# Meteor doesn't wait for the result from a function, returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function, meteor, web-scraping, serverside-javascript

I'm building a small web **scraper** and I have stumbled into the following problem: my applications needs to scrape different parts of a website and put the information into the database. Sometimes it gives crazy results such as duplicated entries, or it returns undefined from a function getPhoto(). However, if I only call that function (and don't run the rest of the script), it returns a correct result!

I have a for loop, that loops through different URL. It goes to each URL and scrapes the following information: 1. title, 2.description, 3. internal link, 4. calls a function that generates an image according to the title (getPhoto(...) ), 5. saves the results to the DB. Everything happens on the server (I'm using Cron jobs, no client interaction)

```
 for (i = 0; i < AllLinks.length; i++) {  

  if (AllLinks[i] != undefined && AllLinks[i] != null && sepLink[2] == "www.fly4free.pl") {

    var t2 = {
      travelTitle: null,
      travelTitle2: null,
      travelTitle3: null,
      travelDescription: null,
      travelDescription2: null,
      travelDescription3: null,
      travelBuy: null,
      travelBuy2: null,
      travelImage: null
    };

    var TravelLink1 = AllLinks[i];
    
    result = HTTP.get(AllLinks[i], {});
    $ = cheerio.load(result.content);

    t2.travelTitle = $('.article__title').text();
    t2.travelDescription = $('.article__content').find('p').first().text();

    if ($("img[src$='//www.fly4free.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/lotJm.png']").parent().attr('href') != null) {
      t2.travelBuy = $("img[src$='//www.fly4free.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/lotJm.png']").parent().attr('href'); // Link to buy
    }
    
    if (t2.travelBuy) {
      if (t2.travelBuy.split('https://').pop().split('http://').pop() != null) {
        t2.travelBuy2 = t2.travelBuy.split('https://').pop().split('http://').pop(); // link ready for DB
      } else {
        t2.travelBuy2 = t2.travelBuy;
      }
    }        

    t2.travelTitle3 = convertCurrencyInText(t2.travelTitle, 'PLN');
    t2.travelDescription3 = convertCurrencyInText(t2.travelDescription, 'PLN');

    translate(t2.travelTitle3, {from: 'pl', to: 'en'}).then(res => {
      t2.travelTitle2 = res.text; // title for DB
      if (t2.travelTitle2) { t2.travelImage = getPhoto(t2.travelTitle2); }

      translate(t2.travelDescription3, {from: 'pl', to: 'en'}).then(response => {
        t2.travelDescription2 = response.text; // description for DB

        if (t2.travelDescription2 != null && t2.travelTitle2 != null && t2.travelBuy2 != null && TravelLink1 != null && t2.travelImage != null) {
          Links.insert({ title: t2.travelTitle2, description:t2.travelDescription2, image: t2.travelImage, buyLink:t2.travelBuy2, link: TravelLink1, datetime: new Date() });
        } 

      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });

    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });

  }

}
```

"AllLinks" contains different URLs. I have problems scraping this URL: http://www.fly4free.pl/na-wakacje-do-toskanii-tanie-loty-do-pizy-z-gdanska-za-170-pln/

getPhoto() function

```
    function getPhoto(title) {

  var travelPlace = nlp(title).match('to *').out('text').replace('to','').trim();
  if (travelPlace) {var travelPlace2 = travelPlace.split(' '); } 
  if (travelPlace2) {var travelPlace3 = travelPlace2[0] + "+" + travelPlace2[1]; } 
  if (travelPlace3) {
    var URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&q="+travelPlace3+"&category=travel&orientation=horizontal";
    var images = (HTTP.get(URL, {}));

    if (images.data.totalHits > 0) {
      var imageLink = images.data.hits[0].webformatURL;
      return imageLink;

    } else if (images.data.totalHits == 0) {
      var URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&q="+travelPlace2[0]+"&category=travel&orientation=horizontal";
      var images = (HTTP.get(URL, {}));

      if (images.data.totalHits > 0) {
        var imageLink = images.data.hits[0].webformatURL;
        return imageLink;
      }

    }
  } else if (nlp(title).places().data().length > 0) {
    var result = nlp(title).places().data()[0].text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").trim();
    var URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&q="+result+"&category=travel&orientation=horizontal";
    var images = (HTTP.get(URL, {}));

    if (images.data.totalHits > 0) {
      var imageLink = images.data.hits[0].webformatURL;
      return imageLink;
    }

  } else {
    var title2 = title.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").split(" ");
    if (title2) {
      for(i = 0; i < title2.length; i++) {

        if (cities[title2[i]] == 1) {
          
          var URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&q="+title2[i]+"&category=travel&orientation=horizontal";
          var images = (HTTP.get(URL, {}));

          if (images.data.totalHits > 0) {
            var imageLink = images.data.hits[0].webformatURL;
            return imageLink;
          }

        } else {

          var URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&q=travel&category=travel&orientation=horizontal";
          var images = (HTTP.get(URL, {}));

          if (images.data.totalHits > 0) {
            var imageLink = images.data.hits[0].webformatURL;
            return imageLink;
          }


        }
      }
    }  
  }

}
```

I try to console log the results - sometimes I get a correct image from getPhoto(), but an undefined link from t2.travelBuy, sometimes vice versa. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I saw some people are using Promises or async/await functions on that kind of problems. Do you think that would help me? How should I change my code in order to scrape the website without getting "undefined"?

"translate" comes from "google-translate-api" package

Comment: Didn't read your whole thing to be honest, but the short answer is: it sounds like an async problem. Either return a promise or put your function that isn't getting the right data in the callback of the function that sets the data.

Answer (score 0):

you can try var new_func = Meteor.wrapAsync(YOUR FUNCTION THAT HAVE CALLBACK) and the when you use new_func() it will return the result as you would expect from normal function instead of waiting for callback

Comment: my functions don't have callbacks. How could I change them?

Comment: you HTTP.get have callback but it can be omitted in the server but to get the error you have to catch it instead

Comment: `try {
      const result = HTTP.call('GET', 'http://api.twitter.com/xyz', {
        params: { user: userId }
      });
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      // Got a network error, timeout, or HTTP error in the 400 or 500 range.
      return false;
    }`